# Stream order and stream number

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am Getting higher stream number for lower order streams in my analysis on ArcGIS,  order 6 has more streams than order 5. is this common in morphometric analysis?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without a little more information on your project and files, it seems like your GRIDCODE value stands for your `ranking order`, and the `count` merely stands for the size (number of cells) of your feature.

If that's the case, it means that your stream of rank 6 is bigger than that of 5. I'm not sure if it's logically reasonable without knowing a little more about what you are trying to do. If the order of your stream is solely decided by the size of each, then probably no.

Comment: i am trying to do a morphometric analysis for a clipped basin from a DEM. i want to know the stream network in the basin. how many channels or segments and the stream orders as well. that is my work.

Comment: However, if i use a raster calculator, say 500 or 400 or 300, the ranking and count will reasonable and stream numbers will decrease gradually. but the total number of streams will be less with the raster calculator

Comment: I need a little more information on the raster calculator part. What did you do exactly with `raster calculator` and what was the formula you used with it?